# Unity JavaScript OnCollisionEnter with 2D gameObject

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Im trying to destroy a gameObject (in my case a 2d ball) when my player comes into contact with  it with the built-in OnCollisionEnter  function. My script is only attached to the player. Both the player, and the ball(battery) have 2d box colliders, and rigidbodies. Perhaps the fact that they are 2d colliders instead of regular has something to do with the problem? Ah! yes I almost forgot to mention the problem; it's not working. Its niether destroying, or printing "hit".... and oh yes, i DID name the ball "battery". thAnks so much I would very much appreciate some help!

UnityScript Code:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(batt : Collision)
{
    if(batt.collider.name == "battery")
    {
        Destroy(batt.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using unity's 2d toolset, instead of OnCollisionEnter you use OnCollisionEnter2D, and inside the variables, instead of batt: Collision, you need to change it to batt: Collision2D, hope this helps :), also, you said your both objects have 2d box colliders and rigidbodies, make sure it's a 2d rigidbody and not a 3d rigidbody (default)

Comment: Awesome its working perfectly now. I knew it had something to do with the conference's in 2D

Answer (score 0):

Well, its hard to debug collisions in Unity, and even harder without knowing your whole project. But a few things:

1) Make sure you have rigidbodies attached to your gameObjects that you want to receive events

2) For your code I'm not too sure ( since I mostly do C# ) but basically:

```
OnCollisionEnter( Collision batt ){
    if ( batt.gameObject.name == "battery" ){
        //Do what you want it to do
    }
}
```

I think essentially you might not be pulling in the right name. If that doesn't work, try to place a debugger breakpoint on the OnCollisionEnter to see if it is being called.